# CakePHP Facebook plugin: custom login button image

Tags: cakephp, authentication, facebook

I am trying to replace the default image with a custom one, but with no success. I have tried applying some CSS classes that put my image over Facebook's, but it gives me an error: `truncated image`.

How can I replace the custom login button? I would appreciate if you can give me a 'caky' solution, as I use CakePHP Facebook Plugin for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I the plugin's helper is simply wrapping the default button produced by fb:login-button.  You will need to hook up the js manually if you want make it look different.

More info about FB.login() [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/), but for example, assuming you're using jQuery:

```
<a href='#' id='login' class='customLoginLink'>Login<a>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#login').click(function(event) {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.session) {
                // user successfully logged in
            } else {
                // user cancelled login
            }
       });
    });
</script>
```

Want it Cake-like? Wrap it in an element.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helped! In the JS function, do I have to write something instead of those comments, or simply let them blank?

Comment: You would want some code there to update the page as necessary. For example, on success, you would want to remove the login link and replace it with a logout link and/or link to their account page.